# Failed to deploy WP 8.1 application to the mobile device

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8, visual-studio-2013, windows-phone-8.1

I am using MS Visual Studio 2013 Professional Edition with Update 3. When I try to deply a WP 8.1 to the mobile device, I am facing the following errors.

> Error: DEP3100: Attempts to stop the application on target machine "127.0.0.1" failed. 
>       This may cause the deployment to fail. 
>       The network connection to the Visual Studio Remote Debugger has been closed.
>
> Error DEP2300: The deployment tool (TailoredDeploy.exe) failed to run on the target machine "127.0.0.1". 
>       The object invoked has disconnected from its clients.

I have earlier deployed application to this mobile device.

Why am I facing such an error now?

Comment: Try manually uninstalling the app.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I manually uninstalled the app. And when I tried to re-install the app, the same error occurred. But the solution was more simpler than I thought. I restarted the phone after switching it off. Voila. Worked. I installed the app once again. Successfully debugged the application & was able to deploy it to the device.

PS: But still I don't know why this error occurred.